# If <a> has title, addClass jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, addclass

I'm trying to get jQuery automatically detect if a link has a title. I want to create a tooltip for every title attribute.

HTML:

```
<a title="This is a title" href="#">link with tooltip</a>
```

How can jQuery detect if a link has a title, and then add a class to that ?

??

```
$(window).load(function(){ 


    $('a[title=""]').addClass('toolTip');

});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
$('a[title]').addClass('toolTip');
```

Attribute selector is the key :D Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value. Finds elements with a title attribute.

More info [Has Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

Answer (score 3):

Close

```
$("a[title]").addClass("toolTip")
```

You can use the attribute selector to check for existence of attributes.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
$('a[title]').addClass('toolTip');
```

Using an attribute selector without a value will just check if the attribute exists, regardless of its value.

Refer to [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).